# Complex table issues

Tags: tables, columns

I have a problem with my table.
I'm trying to create a table, into a two column document.
It is a "complex" table with multiple layer. I'm using booktab and multicol.
In the rest of my document, everything is built into the 'class' which is 2 column...

I have a the following problem: file ended while scanning document for multcolumn. Anyone can explain me my issue and how to resolve it ?

Cheers !

```
\usepackage{booktabs,bm}
\newcolumntype{N}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{.5in}}
\newcolumntype{G}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2in}}   

\begin{table*}
\caption{Reliability of short maximal-cycling and jumping -related indices of performance.}
\begin{tabular}{N N N N N N N N N N}\toprule

\multicolumn{4}{N}{\textbf{empty}} & \multicolumn{3}{N}{Intra-day reliability} & \multicolumn{3}{N}{Inter-day reliability} \\
\cline{5-7}
\cline{8-10}
\multicolumn{1}{N}{\textbf{Tests} & \textbf{Variable} & \textbf{Performance} & \textbf{SWC (\%)} & \textbf{TE (\%)} & \textbf{Magnitude} & \textbf{ICC} & 
\textbf{TE (\%)} & \textbf{Magnitude} & \textbf{ICC} \\
\cmidrule(lr){1-10}
\multicolumn{1}{ N } CMJ    & Height (cm) & 43.1$\pm$4.9 &  2.3\%   & 4.4$\pm$1.2   & small &   0.88$\pm$0.09   &   5.4$\pm$1.4 &   small   & 0.81$\pm$0.12 \\
\multicolumn{1}{ N } CMJ    & Peak velocity (m.s-1)&    3.3$\pm$0.3&    1.7\% & 3.2$\pm$0.8 &   small & 0.87$\pm$0.09   &   4.0$\pm$1.0 &   small & 0.8$\pm$0.13 \\
\multicolumn{1}{ N } CMJ &  Mean Power (W) &    3304.1$\pm$961.5 &  5.8\% & 16.8$\pm$4.7 &  moderate &  0.65$\pm$0.2 &      20.2$\pm$5.8 &  moderate &  0.50$\pm$0.26 \\
\multicolumn{1}{ N } Cycling &  Max Power (W) & 1219.4$\pm$159.5 &  2.6\% & 2.6$\pm$0.7 &   small & 0.97$\pm$0.02 &     3.4$\pm$0.9 &   small & 0.94$\pm$0.04 \\
\multicolumn{1}{ N } Cycling &  Mean Power (W) &    1100.5$\pm$129.2 &  2.3\% & 3$\pm$0.8 & small & 0.94$\pm$0.04 &     3.2$\pm$0.8 &   small & 0.94$\pm$0.05 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}
```

Comment: The full error message already gives you the cause of this problem: You forgot a `}`.  The line should actually start as follows: `\multicolumn{1}{N}{\textbf{Tests}} &`. Nevertheless, the spacing of your cells looks strange, at least in the example I used to compile. To solve this, a MWE including the documentclass and all relevant packages would be needed.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to put the contents of a `multicolumn` cell between two braces `{}`. The first of these errors is this line `\multicolumn{1}{N}{\textbf{Tests}}` and the same error is repeated in subsequent lines.

```
\begin{table*}
\caption{Reliability of short maximal-cycling and jumping -related indices of performance.}
\begin{tabular}{N N N N N N N N N N}\toprule

\multicolumn{4}{N}{\textbf{empty}} & \multicolumn{3}{N}{Intra-day reliability} & \multicolumn{3}{N}{Inter-day reliability} \\
\cline{5-7}
\cline{8-10}
\multicolumn{1}{N}{\textbf{Tests}} & \textbf{Variable} & \textbf{Performance} & \textbf{SWC (\%)} & \textbf{TE (\%)} & \textbf{Magnitude} & \textbf{ICC} & 
\textbf{TE (\%)} & \textbf{Magnitude} & \textbf{ICC} \\
\cmidrule(lr){1-10}
\multicolumn{1}{ N } {CMJ}    & Height (cm) & 43.1$\pm$4.9 &  2.3\%   & 4.4$\pm$1.2   & small &   0.88$\pm$0.09   &   5.4$\pm$1.4 &   small   & 0.81$\pm$0.12 \\
\multicolumn{1}{ N } {CMJ}    & Peak velocity (m.s-1)&    3.3$\pm$0.3&    1.7\% & 3.2$\pm$0.8 &   small & 0.87$\pm$0.09   &   4.0$\pm$1.0 &   small & 0.8$\pm$0.13 \\
\multicolumn{1}{ N } {CMJ} &  Mean Power (W) &    3304.1$\pm$961.5 &  5.8\% & 16.8$\pm$4.7 &  moderate &  0.65$\pm$0.2 &      20.2$\pm$5.8 &  moderate &  0.50$\pm$0.26 \\
\multicolumn{1}{ N } {Cycling} &  Max Power (W) & 1219.4$\pm$159.5 &  2.6\% & 2.6$\pm$0.7 &   small & 0.97$\pm$0.02 &     3.4$\pm$0.9 &   small & 0.94$\pm$0.04 \\
\multicolumn{1}{ N } {Cycling} &  Mean Power (W) &    1100.5$\pm$129.2 &  2.3\% & 3$\pm$0.8 & small & 0.94$\pm$0.04 &     3.2$\pm$0.8 &   small & 0.94$\pm$0.05 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}
```